# VTK abstract picker for multiple actors of different opacity value

Tags: c++, vtk

I am new to VTK. I would like to know how VTK abstract picker behaves for multiple actors of different opacity values. Let's consider two actors, with one
inside another. When I set the opacity of the outer surface to 0.3, while
keeping the opacity of the inner one 1.0.Since the outer one is semi-transparent, I can see the inner actor in the overlap region of the two actors. When I perform picking in that region,the resulting coordinates is from the inner surface itself, and when I pick some point other than the overlap region,I am getting outer surface coordinates. How can I perform picking operation based on opacity values? Such that i want to pick one actor at a time. Anybody please help..

Answer (score 1):

[vtkAbstractPicker](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkAbstractPicker.html) is, as the name suggest, just as an abstract class that defines interface for picking, but nothing more. When choosing actual pickers, you basically have a choice between picking based on ray casting or "color picking" using graphical hardware (see the linked documentation for actual vtk classes that implement those).

Now to the actual problem, if I understood what you wrote correctly, you are facing a rather simple sorting problem. The opacity can be seen as kind of a priority - the actors with higher opacity should be picked even if they are inside others with lower opacity, right? Then all you need to do is get all the actors that are underneath your mouse cursor and then choose the one with highest opacity, or the closest one for cases when they have the same opacity.

I think the easiest way to implement this is using the [vtkPropPicker](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPropPicker.html) (`vtkProp` is a parent class for actor so this is a good picker for picking actors). It is one of the "hardware" pickers, using the color picking algorithm. The basic algorithm is that each pickable object is rendered using a different color into a hidden buffer (texture). This color (which after all is a 32-bit number like any other) serves as an ID of that object: when the user clicks on a screen, you read the color of the pixel from the picking texture on the clicked coordinates and then you simply look into the map of objects under the ID that is equal to that color and you have the object. Obviously, it cannot use any transparency - the individual colors are IDs of the objects, blending them would make them impossible to identify.

However, the `vtkPropPicker` provides a method:

```
// Perform a pick from the user-provided list of vtkProps 
// and not from the list of vtkProps that the render maintains.
// If something is picked, a 1 is returned, otherwise 0 is returned.
// Use the GetViewProp() method to get the instance of vtkProp that was picked.
int PickProp (double selectionX, double selectionY,
              vtkRenderer *renderer, vtkPropCollection *pickfrom);
```

What you can do with this is simply first call `PickProp(mouseClickX, mouseClickY, renderer of your render window, pickfrom)` providing only the highest-priority actors in the `pickfrom` collection i.e. the actors with the highest opacity. Underneath, this will do a render of all the provided actors using the color-coding algorithm and tell you which actor is underneath the specified coordinates. If it picks something (return value is 1, you call GetViewProp on it and it gives you the pointer to your picked actor), you keep it, if it does not (return value is 0), you call it again, this time providing actors with lower opacity and so on until you pick something or you test all the actors.

You can do the same with the ray-casting pickers like `vtkPicker` as well - it cast a ray underneath your mouse and gives you all intersections with everything in the scene. But the vtkPicker's API is optimized for finding the closest intersection, it might be a bit of work to get all of them and then sorting them and in the end, I believe the solution using `vtkPropPicker` will be faster anyway.

If this solution is good, you might want to look at [vtkHardwareSelector](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkHardwareSelector.html), which uses the same algorithm, but unlike the `vtkPropPicker` allows you to access the underlying picking texture many times, so that you don't need to re-render for every picking query. Depending on how your rendering pipeline is set up, this might be a more efficient solution (= if you make a lot of picking without updating the scene).